# Build Automation & MySQL Workbench Scripting: Forward Engineer SQL CREATE SCRIPT

Tags: scripting, lua, build-automation, mysql-workbench

I'm currently looking into automating a software build process that includes a database schema defined in MySQL Workbench.

Using Workbench's scripting capabilities, I'd like to open a Workbench document and export its schema as an SQL CREATE script.

**What I'd like to know is if there is a function that exports the entire schema in one step as Workbench's *File* | *Export* | *Forward Engineer SQL CREATE Script*, automatically handling any dependencies between tables.**

I've found some candidates in the `DbMySQL` module that *might* do that (`generateSQL(GrtNamedObject, dict, string)` and `makeSQLExportScript(GrtNamedObject, dict, dict, dict)`), however I'm confused about the parameters they expect – the first one could be the schema object, but what are the other arguments ?

Could anyone tell me if my assumption is correct and/or provide me with usage examples ?

So far, I've come up with a manual solution (note that this currently does not sort the tables according to their FK relations):

```
local o = assert(io.open("/tmp/create.sql", "wb"));
foreach_table_all(function (t)
    o:write(DbMySQL:makeCreateScriptForObject(t) .. ";\n\n")
end)
o:close()
```

The question is related to [How to generate SQL Script from MySQL Workbench using Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241712/how-to-generate-sql-script-from-mysql-workbench-using-command-line), however the answer found there is really abstract and tells nothing about actually using the scripting features of MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that other [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241712/how-to-generate-sql-script-from-mysql-workbench-using-command-line) got [answered in Dec 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20406877/419404), courtesy of [madhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750510/madhead), albeit with minor trivial code glitches, and in Python rather than Lua, so here the Python version that is working for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# MySQL Workbench Python script
# <description>
# Written in MySQL Workbench 6.0.8

import os
import grt
from grt.modules import DbMySQLFE

c = grt.root.wb.doc.physicalModels[0].catalog
DbMySQLFE.generateSQLCreateStatements(c, c.version, {
    'GenerateDrops' : 1,
    'GenerateSchemaDrops' : 1,
    'OmitSchemata' : 1,
    'GenerateUse' : 1
})
DbMySQLFE.generateSQLCreateStatements(c, c.version, {})
DbMySQLFE.createScriptForCatalogObjects(os.path.dirname(grt.root.wb.docPath) + '/ddl.sql', c, {})
```

Looks rather big compared to the loop variant but *might* bring some benefits (haven't tested, but I could imagine Workbench being able to figure out the proper order to create tables etc.).

Also I am unsure about whether this has existed when I was asking the question, but anyway, this works on a recent version.

Comment: Any hint on what option to use for excluding certain tables from the export, as it is possible in the GUI?

Comment: See my question. It uses `foreach_table_all()`, and the callback function can check for the table and just decide not to write it. Simple as that.

Comment: Any way to drop the schema identifier in this approach?

Comment: Haven't looked at it, so I'd refer you to the docs/help. But you probably could just hack and use string replace in most cases, I guess.

Comment: I can't find any docs for the options, but looks like they are mainly processed [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/modules/db.mysql/src/db_mysql_diffsqlgen.cpp#L1383). Looks like there's both `TableFilterList` and `OmitSchemas`