# How to get SQL script from MySQL Workbench .mwb file programatically?

Tags: mysql-workbench, vagrantfile

My db schema is designed in MySQL Workbench and saved as a .wmb file. In my Vagrantfile I want to generate the SQL schema for my db and then load it. Smth like this:

```
MySQLWorkbench --generateSQL design.wmb --output schema.sql
```

so that later i can do this

```
mysql < 'schema.sql'
```

Can't seem to find the CLI for MySQLWorkbench to do this. Is this possible? Or other suggestions to achieve the same result.

I found this answer [How to generate SQL Script from MySQL Workbench using Command Line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241712/how-to-generate-sql-script-from-mysql-workbench-using-command-line/20406877#20406877)

but it's half-baked and I don't understand how to input my design file name into the script in order to get the SQL out. And I don't have enough rep to post a follow-up question in that thread.